# Switch between JPanels using JFrames

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, cardlayout

I have two views : test1 and test2

Switching from test1 to test 2 works fine, but when I switch back from test2 the contentPanel is empty. 
This is my code.
Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

**test1**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JButton;


public class test1 extends JFrame {

JPanel contentPane;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                test1 frame = new test1();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public test1() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    setContentPane(contentPane);

    JButton btnView = new JButton("View2");
    contentPane.add(btnView, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    btnView.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            contentPane.removeAll();
            contentPane.invalidate();
            test2 obj=new test2();
            obj.contentPane.setVisible(true);
            contentPane.add(obj.contentPane);
            ((JPanel)contentPane).revalidate();
            contentPane.repaint();          }
    });
}

}
```

**test2**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class test2 extends JFrame {

JPanel contentPane;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                test2 frame = new test2();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public test2() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    JLabel lblThisIsView = new JLabel("this is view 2!");
    lblThisIsView.setBounds(178, 107, 110, 14);
    contentPane.add(lblThisIsView);

    JButton btnView = new JButton("View 1!");
    btnView.setBounds(168, 161, 89, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnView);

    btnView.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            contentPane.removeAll();
            contentPane.invalidate();
            test1 obj=new test1();
            obj.contentPane.setVisible(true);
            contentPane.add(obj.contentPane);
            ((JPanel)contentPane).revalidate();
            contentPane.repaint();
        }
    });
}
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by switching? You run in this sequence? test1 > test2 > test2? Am I right?

Comment: Yeah, when I'm in test1 I want to go to test2 and vice versa. It works from test1 to test2 but not the other way round.

Comment: Take a look at [How to use CardLayouts](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html), it'll do what you're trying to achieve, only simpler

Comment: +1 for sscce, +1 to @MadProgrammers comment, see here for  more [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice) you could also use `JDialog` 1) do not extend `JFrame` class unnecessarily. 2) use a [`LayoutManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html), not `null`/`Absolute` Layout

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To the current frame I just set:

```
"classname.this.setVisible(false);"
```

Frame switching works fine now. It isn't the right method but my project submission is today and the solution is simple enough to implement everywhere.

Comment: @Venomal The only place where JavaScript is mentioned is in your comment.

Answer (score 3):

It's a basic problem with layouts. In `test1.java` you have added the components with `BorderLayout`. But not in `test2.java`.

The layout of test2 should be `BorderLayout`. After that all the components should be added with below syntax -

```
contentPane.add(lblThisIsView,BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Completed code of `test2.java` -

```
public test2() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

        JLabel lblThisIsView = new JLabel("this is view 2!");
        lblThisIsView.setBounds(178, 107, 110, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblThisIsView,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JButton btnView = new JButton("View 1!");
        btnView.setBounds(168, 161, 89, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnView,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        btnView.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                contentPane.removeAll();
                contentPane.invalidate();
                test1 obj = new test1();
                obj.contentPane.setVisible(true);
                contentPane.add(obj.contentPane);
                ((JPanel) contentPane).revalidate();
                contentPane.repaint();
            }
        });
    }
```

Total code is [here](https://gist.github.com/4213984).

---

As seen from comments best way is to use `CardLayout` -
To add panels -

```
public CardLayoutHelper(JPanel panel, JPanel... panels) {
        this(panel);
        for (int i = 0; i < panels.length; i++) {
            JPanel jPanel = panels[i];
            panel.add(jPanel.getName(), jPanel);
        }
    }
```

To switch the Panel -

```
 public void switchPanel(String name) {
            layout.show(panel, name);
            panel.revalidate();
            panel.repaint();
        }
```

You can get the `CardLayoutHelper` from [github](https://gist.github.com/4214039).

Comment: yep i agree... But I wanted to find the problem in the code. `CardLayout` definitely is the best solution. Edited the question for it.

Comment: That works only for the label. If I pass the entire content as the parameter it doesn't work.

Comment: It works for the button as well. You have to change - `contentPane.add(btnView,BorderLayout.SOUTH);`.

Comment: No, thing is I want the entire thing added at a go. The whole content pane. In my main project I have too many elements to add manually.

Comment: But then the layouts should match. But for these kind of cases use the `CardLayoutHelper`. Because it's never acceptable to use Many jFrames in a production application